# Allow object access to its owning object's attribute

Tags: python

I've got a whole bunch of classes that are effectively algorithms, and they all inherit from a Mechanism class. I then have a MechanismStack class which holds a list of a bunch of these algorithm classes, they are all interchangeable/modular - i.e. output of Mechanism1.encode() goes into Mechanism2.encode() as the input etc. (effectively a queue of functions).

A couple of these classes produce extra data than just the output. I want to store this extra data in the MechanismStack class (which is also an object - there are multiple different stacks comprised of different algorithms)

```
class MechanismStack:
    self.stack = [Mechanism1(), Mechanism2(), Mechanism3()]
    self.attribute = list()
    def encode(self, input):
        #process input through self.stack Mechanisms

class Mechanism1(Mechanism):
    def function(self, input):
        #code
        owningMechanismStack.attribute = ['some', 'list']

myStack = MechanismStack()
myStack.encode('myInputString')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the owning `MechanismStack` as a property of `Mechanism`, which you supply when calling the constructor.

```
class Mechanism:
    def __init__(self, owner):
        this.owningMechanismStack = owner

class MechanismStack:
    self.stack = [Mechanism1(self), Mechanism2(self), Mechanism3(self)]
    ...
```

Comment: This was my first thought, and what I've currently got implemented, however I've only added it for the Mechanisms that generate extra metadata. Would it be better to add the owner for all or just the ones that need access to the MechanismStack?

Comment: That probably depends on overall design. I did it in the superclass to keep it flexible, so that `MechanismStack` doesn't need to know the details of which `Mechanism` subclasses need back-references and which don't.